# FlowLayoutPanel scroll cutting off early. Not displaying all child controls

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I have a secondary form with a docked FlowLayoutPanel that is dynamically populated with a number of DataGridViews.  When there are a large number, around 100 or more, the vertical scroll will not display all the child controls.  Sometimes they are cut off mid control.  If I resize the window it will change the number of controls and how much of the last row of controls will be displayed, but not in any pattern I can recognize.  When I maximize the form it is very likely to display all the child controls, but not guaranteed.

The closest I've found to this problem has recommended using SyspendLayout/ResumeLayout around the addition of the controls, but this has done nothing for me.

```
    private void PopulateDisplay()
    {
        previewFlow.SuspendLayout();
        foreach(DataGridView dgv in _Display)
        {
            previewFlow.Controls.Add(dgv);
        }
        previewFlow.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

_Display is List which I populate earlier via code.  Each is populated by a SQL query that returns a different number of results.

I would like the form to show all the DataGridViews on any size form without having to worry that something is incomplete.

Comment: You can't display anything beyond 32k pixels. If your DGVs are too large for the numbers you should redesign, e.g. by using virtual scrolling. See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808934/fake-scrolling-containers-with-very-many-controls/39810717?s=3|0.0000#39810717)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the pixel limit; that is likely what I'm running into.  I also didn't know about virtual scrolling, thanks for the lead.  But if the area to be displayed is fixed, how come I can sometimes get more data than other times?

Comment: You don't. But the DGVs may have different sizes, number of rows, fonts, margins etc.