# FlowLayoutPanel Problem - Adding 1000 Custom Controls with label. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, performance, flowlayoutpanel

I'm having problem with FlowLayoutPanel, i have custom control created with labels on it, looks like row with size: 250:20. I'm adding it to Flowlayoutpanel programmatically. When i Add 200 or 300 rows on FlowLayoutPanel, it seems ok, but when i'm importing text file with say 1000 lines, so it needs to create 1000 rows (mycontrol) to FlowLayoutPanel, it tooks 30 seconds its slow. How to add it faster and also delete faster.

My FlowLayoutPanel is covered with custom code:

```
  Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        DoubleBuffered = True
        UpdateStyles()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
```

Screenshot Here: [My FlowLayoutPanel and custom Control(Row with Labels)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7ia.jpg)

Adding Items code:

```
                       For Each item As String In MyList
                            Dim a As New customControl
                            Dim col(1) As String
                            col(0) = item
                            col(1) = ""
                            a.lblTxt.Text = item
                            FlowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout()
                            FlowLayoutPanell.Controls.Add(a)
                            FlowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout()
                        Next
```

Deleting Items Code:

```
FlowLayoutPanell.Controls.Clear()
```

I wanted to use ListView, but it has no options like Transparent Color and other stuff to customize, that's why i use FlowLayoutPanel and customControl.

Comment: You could try creating all the controls first and then adding them all in one go with a call to `AddRange`. You should have been doing that anyway. Always add large numbers of items in a single batch with `AddRange` if you can. That said, you really shouldn't have that many controls on a form at the same time anyway and you still might see some sluggishness. You ought to find a way to page the data and thus significantly reduce the number of controls needed at a time.

Comment: Thanks is there any sample of paging the data of FlowLayoutPanel and saving those items.

Comment: Add only as many control as you can see on the screen and reassign/redraw when you scroll.

Comment: There is no inbuilt, just-call-a-method way. You need to determine the logic and write code to implement it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808934/fake-scrolling-containers-with-very-many-controls/39810717#39810717

Comment: Building your own grid control with FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel is a mistake.  Judging from the screenshot, a ListView with View = Details will do just fine.

Comment: But better design of listview or something like that?

Comment: Use `DataGridView` instead. You can get something close to the screenshot and better by just setting some properties in the designer. `RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle`, `GridColor`,  `ColumnHeadersVisible`..etc. See the docs. Also, you can handle the default painting events to draw the different grid parts the way you want.

Comment: Thank you @dr.null, how can i add extra space beetween rows, it is very fast when loading rows and opening files also, very useful bro ;)

Comment: You're Welcome. Increase the row's [`DividerHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.dividerheight?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.DividerHeight)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property.

Answer (score -1):

I know the question it's a bit old but here is an adjusted version of your code:

```
FlowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout()

For Each item As String In MyList
   Dim a As New customControl
   Dim col(1) As String
   col(0) = item
   col(1) = ""
   a.lblTxt.Text = item
   FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(a)
Next

FlowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout()
```

By doing this, you are minimizing the number of layout calculations since the controls will be drawn again once you inserted all the items.

For deleting items, your current approach of using FlowLayoutPanell.Controls.Clear() is appropriate. This removes all controls from the FlowLayoutPanel at once, and you don't need to worry about calling SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout in this case, if it's slow you could try to create a new empty FLP and substitute the current one with it, I'm not sure but it should reduce the time needed.