Performance Issues with Multiple UserControls in a TableLayoutPanel in WinForms
I'm currently developing a WinForms application and facing performance issues when dynamically adding multiple UserControl instances to a TableLayoutPanel. Specifically, I have about 141 instances of a custom user control that I need to display based on a panel.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
public void FillPanel()
{
    panel.Controls.Clear();
    panel.SuspendLayout();


    foreach (var group in )
    {
        Label groupLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = $"FlowLayoutPanel Items",
            Location = new Point(0, currentY),
            AutoSize = true
        };

        panel.Controls.Add(groupLabel);
        currentY += groupLabel.Height ; 


        FlowLayoutPanel flowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            Location = new Point(0, currentY),
            Size = new Size(panel.Width, CalculateHeight()),
            AutoSize = false,
            WrapContents = true
        };

        flowPanel.SuspendLayout();

        foreach (var item in group)
        {
            var myUserControlPanel = new myUserControlPanel(item);
            flowPanel.Controls.Add(myUserControlPanel);
        }

        flowPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
        panel.Controls.Add(flowPanel);
        currentY += flowPanel.Height + 10; 
    }

    panel.AutoScroll = true; 
    panel.ResumeLayout(false);
}

There is about 141 controls (myUserControlPanel) to add to at least 5 FlowLayoutPanels (~25 for each).
I've tried already:
-DoubleBuffering
-Add myUserControlPanel to List<myUserControlPanel> and at them once to panel.Controls.Add(listToAdd.ToArray());
The FillPanel() method takes 50 ms to complete all its tasks. After that, setting the form's Visible property to true takes an additional 5 seconds to display the form and all its controls.
Is there a better layout strategy that would improve performance?

Yes, I have already tried this; it gave me the fastest result, but it is still too slow. I have updated my code in the question.

Isn't that just DoubleBuffering ? Anyway i tried it and there is less flickering but now takes 1sec longer to load...

No, 'myUserControlPanel' is a UserControl which have only one label, 2 small panels and 4 textboxes - user can do some input and then save (by button in main form)

You used 1,000 labels on a single LayoutPanel. I have at least five LayoutPanels added to the main panel (above the label), where each LayoutPanel can contain up to 30 elements (UserControl). As for database queries, there are none; all the data is retrieved before calling the FillPanel() method.

Now I'm confused, I write the same exact thing on new project and it runs instant... Is there any global option that can cause that problem ?

No global option that I know of. VS Designer can be temperamental of course. Glad to hear it's fast, but empathize that it really is unsettling to not know exactly what would make the difference. I'll let you know if I think of anything. If the issue does come back, we might need a little more code and/or a repo to go on where we'd have some kind of shot at reproducing the issue.

BTW being "not reproducible" is one of the reasons someone might vote to close a question. I'm not going to do that since we're having a conversation about it but someone else might, and it's not personal if that happens.

Don't do this panel.Controls.Clear();. Before creating the new controls, loop over the flowPanel.Controls collection and .Dispose(); its controls (your myUserControlPanel) and do the same to the panel.Controls.

See also this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39810717/14171304
